# "Invalid Syntax" in for loop, how do I get the customer number using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, syntax

I have the following code:

```
cust_numb = int(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter: "))
list_customer = []
for y in range(0,cust_numb):
    s = (range(1,cust_numb))
    purch_numb = input("How many purchases did customer %s have? " % (s))
    list_customer.append(purch_numb)
for z in range(0,cust_numb):
  print("Customer %s" % (in range(1,cust_numb)) + "had %s" % (purch_numb) + "purchases.")
```

When I run it, the terminal says:

```
File "main.py", line 8
    print("Customer %s" % (in range(1,cust_numb)) + "had %s" %(purch_numb) + 
"purchases.")
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I have no idea what I did wrong.  Any help?

Also, yes, I understand that some of my %s strings are wrong as well.

Comment: `print("Customer %s" %z + "had %s" % (purch_numb) + "purchases.")` maybe?

Comment: `in` is a binary operator; where's the left operand?

Comment: The `in` operator worked in line 3, so I'm confused if I did something different.

Comment: What is the intend of writing this `(in range(1,cust_numb)) `

Comment: I'm new to python, so I was trying to print out customer 1, customer 2, etc, for however many customers the user inputs on line 1.  I thought this would add as many customers as the user needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing another for loop, just get the number from the previous for loop and add one to it so it counts from 1 if you would like it to.

Tested and works

```
cust_numb = int(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter: "))
list_customer = {}
customers = 1
for y in range(0,cust_numb):
    purch_numb = int(input("How many purchases did customer %s have? " % (customers)))
    list_customer.update({"customer{}".format(customers) : purch_numb})
    customers = customers + 1

info = ""
for customer in range(0,cust_numb):
    info += "%s " % ("customer{}".format(customer+1)) + "had %s " % (list_customer["customer{}".format(customer+1)]) + "purchases. "

print(info)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have one more question if you don't mind... how do I make `purch_numb` print how many purchases each individual customer had?  After I input the the `purch_numb`s it always prints one.  So if I simply did `purch_numb + 1`, it would print as two.  I want it to print the number of purchases each individual customer did.  Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what you are asking. Do you mean print every purchase as in, a customer makes 2 purchases so that customer prints 2 times? As it currently prints the customer number with the amount of purchases for me.

Comment: On my end it says `Enter number of unique customers then press enter: 2
How many purchases did customer 1 have? 4
How many purchases did customer 2 have? 6
Customer 1 had 6 purchases.
Customer 2 had 6 purchases.` but I want it to say `customer 1 had 4 purchases customer 2 had 6 purchases` if you would like me to share the code let me know

Comment: I have updated my answer, this now prints `customer 1 had 1 purchases customer 2 had 1 purchases` if you were to have 2 customers.

Comment: right, but it still says each customer has the same number of purchases even if I input different numbers for each customer.  Also, I'm later going to be saving each customer number with their purchases number in a dictionary, and then print the customer numbers with the most purchases in greatest to least order, so if that changes anything.

Comment: I have updated the code, now it prints the different purchases.

Comment: it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    info += "customer %s " % (customer+1) + "had %s " % (list_customer[customer]) + "purchases "
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Was that using all the code copied above?

Comment: I have the following code because I wanted to change something in the first `for` loop: `cust_numb = int(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter: "))
list_customer = []
customers = 1
for y in range(0,cust_numb):
     purch_numb = int(input("How many purchases did customer %s have? " % (customers)))
     customers = customers + 1 
info = ""
for customer in range(0,cust_numb):
    info += "customer %s " % (customer+1) + "had %s " % (list_customer[customer]) + "purchases. "
print(info)`  sorry I know this is sloppy.  I can post as a new question and reply with the link

Comment: Below `customers = customers + 1` add `list_customer.append(purch_numb)` inside the `for` loop. This adds each purchase number to the list, which is used on the `info +=` line.

Comment: thanks!  One more thing if you don't mind... how would I go about saving each customer with entered amount of  purchases to a dictionary?

Comment: I have updated the code, so now it saves it into a dictionary and the info uses the dictionary. The dictionaries get stored in the list as well.

Comment: This is the return `Enter number of unique customers then press enter: 4
How many purchases did customer 1 have? 2
How many purchases did customer 2 have? 5
How many purchases did customer 3 have? 1
How many purchases did customer 4 have? 3
customer 1 had 2 purchases. customer 2 had 5 purchases. customer 3 had 1 purchases. customer 4 had 3 purchases.
{'customer': 4, 'purchases': 3}` I want it to return {Customer 1: 2, Customer 2: 5, etc.}, later I am going to print out the 3 customers with the most purchases

Comment: I changed the code again, that should be what you want.